# Kotlinx Json deserialize Retrofit null json response body

Tags: json, retrofit2, kotlinx.serialization

I am using retrofit with "jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:0.8.0"

I've got an API call that returns JSON `null` as "not found" response. I thought that just marking return type as nullable will be enought like this

```
suspend fun getUserRights(...) : UserRightsApiDto?
```

But every time I get `null` JSON value, exception `kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the object '{', but had 'EOF' instead JSON input: null` is thrown.

How can I fix this and get simple `null`?